# Table view cell segue to view controller not working (Swift)

Tags: xcode, swift, uitableview, navigation, segue

I have a table view cell, which I am trying to connect to a view controller (table view is menu, titled equations) (view controller also has navigation controller and navigation bar, titled quadratics), however, when I control-click the table view cell and drag to the view controller and select "show", it works in the build, but it does not show a back button in the view controller, would there be any way to fix this (preferably with a story board and not programmatically).

Also, how would I make the animation from table view to view controller a right to left slide, and vice versa?

[image: screen shot of story board]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to have the second navigation controller in between your 2nd and 3rd view controller. Delete the navigation controller between your menu (table view controller) and equations view. And create a segue between them directly. This will add the equations view to the navigation stack and you will get the desired animation and back button automatically.

Comment: I'm sorry, my question was badly worded, the equations table view is the menu, and the quadratics is the main view controller I want to go to. I have edited my original question. So do I delete the navigation controller before the equations page? Will I need to add any navigations bars?

Comment: I tried what I thought you meant based on my question, thank you very much, it worked perfectly!

Comment: Yes. You will get the navigation bars and back button. You can set the title of your second view controller in it's view did load method.